# Is there a way to use a var in this call?

Tags: reactjs

Currently I have 12 if statements to check and set the var monthToday. 
I was wondering if there is a simpler solution to this. 
Any help appreciated :)

```
var dateToday = new Date();

var day = { day: "numeric" };
var dayToday = dateToday.toLocaleDateString("en", day); // returns 13
var month = { month: "long" };
var monthToday = dateToday.toLocaleDateString("en", month); // returns July

var displayNames = '';
```

// Until now I had 12 if statements to set var displayNames

// data is an import of .json file - "month" : [{'day' : '1', 'name' : 'something'}] .....

```
if (monthToday == "July") {
displayNames = data.July[dayToday].name; // sets to whatever is in the name value in .json of July 13
```

// and so on for each month

// I was thinking of trying something like this instead of if statements but using monthToday does not want to work

```
var displayNames = data.monthToday[dayToday].name;

return .....
```

Comment: I feel like this could work: `var displayNames = data[monthToday][dayToday].name`, give it a shot!

Comment: Try this approach, `data[monthToday][dayToday].name`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript exist a feature that anable to acess a `property` of an object by given a key of this property in `string` form. Let me show you.

For axemple, if you a an object call person wich have properties like `name` and `age` .  You want to acess property `age`:

```
let person = { name: 'Sarah Connor', age: 34}
```

You can do this:

```
person['age'] = 20;

console.log(person['age']); // 20
```

Your code snippet will be like that for the JSON **struct you show**

```
displayNames = data[monthToday][0][dayToday].name
```